# Pointer to const: why is ptr[1] also read-only?

Tags: c, pointers

I understand that a pointer to const is a pointer through which the value of the variable that the pointer points cannot be changed. Therefore, in the following example, I expect the compiler to raise an error:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    const int *ptr = &a;
    ptr[0]++;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, why would there also be an error with the following example?

```
int main()
{
    int a = 42;
    const int *ptr = &a;
    ptr[1]++;

    return 0;
}
```

This second example (with `ptr[1]++`) throws `error: increment of read-only location ‘*(ptr + 4)’`. Therefore it seems that not only the value of the variable that the pointer points cannot be changed, but also the values of other related memory locations cannot be changed either.

What is the exact behaviour regarding this? Where is this behaviour referenced? For example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer does not seem to be clear about this to me.

Comment: Everything accessed through the pointer is constant, not just the first item.

Comment: Those memory locations are not related, this is just undefined behavior anyway. And _if_ the pointer would point to the beginning of an array, it would be const for __all__ of those elements.

Comment: `const` is not an attribute of the pointer. It's part of the datatype that it points to.

Comment: Note that in your 2nd example, `ptr[1]++` is UB because `a` is only a single element (i.e. it's a scalar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration:

```
const int *ptr;
```

Specifies that `ptr` is a pointer to a `const int`, so you aren't allowed to change what it points to through that pointer.

The expression `ptr + n` (recalling that `x[y]` is the same as `*(x + y)`) also has type `const int *`, so you can't change what *that* points to either.  This is spelled out in sectin 6.5.6p8 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding additive operators:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
> result has the type of the pointer operand.   ...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the standard, which I found useful.

Comment: Re “you aren't allowed to change what it points to through that pointer”: `int x = 3; const int *ptr = &x; * (int *) ptr = 4;` changes `x` through `ptr` and is fully defined C code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wouldn't call that changing `x` though `ptr`, but rather changing `x` though a pointer obtained via a cast.

Comment: I would update to the c17 standard rather than using c11. I know the changes aren't massive but there's some important language "bug fixes" in there amongst the TRs :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is explained in the documentation you linked to:

> **Constness**\
>
> - If *cv* appears before `*` in the pointer declaration, it is part of *decl-specifier-seq* and applies to the pointed-to object.

Since you have `const int` before `*`, it means the pointed-to object consists of integers that may not be modified through this pointer. Indexing the pointer doesn't change this declaration; when you use a pointer as an array, the declaration describes all the array elements.

Comment: Re “it means the pointed-to object consists of constant integers”: That is not what it means. A pointer to a `const` qualified type only means, in effect, “I want a diagnostic if I attempt to modify an object through this type.” It is entirely allowed to set a `const int *` to point to `int` objects that are not `const`.

Comment: I've clarified the wording.

Answer (score 4):

The declarator `const int *ptr` creates the `ptr` variable with a type "pointer to `const int`"<sup>(a)</sup>.

It doesn't matter *how* you manipulate `ptr` to point somewhere else, it carries that type with it<sup>(b)</sup>. Hence it's invalid to attempt changing the thing that it points to, even if that thing is itself not `const`.

So, in the following example, `num` is not `const`, so you can change it directly or through the non-`const` pointer, but you *cannot* change it through the `const` pointer:

```c
int main(void) {
    int num = 0;

    num = 1;  // OK.

    int *p_num = &num;
    *p_num = 2;  // OK.

    const int *cp_num = &num;
    *cp_num = 3;  // Not OK.
}
```

For the "language lawyers" amongst us, this is covered in several sections of the standard (C17 used here, other iterations of the standard may have different section numbers, or even totally different text).

---

First of those is `6.7 Declarations /6`, which shows that the type of the things being declared are done *partly* in the specifiers (e.g., `const int`) and *partly* in the declarator (e.g., `*cp_num = &num`)<sup>(c)</sup>. The text follows with my emphasis:

> The declaration specifiers consist of a sequence of specifiers that indicate the linkage, storage duration, and ***part of the type*** of the entities that the declarators denote.
>
> The *init-declarator-list* is a comma-separated sequence of declarators, each of which may have ***additional type information,*** or an initializer, or both. The declarators contain the identifiers (if any) being declared.

---

The second can be found in `6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators /4`, covering the unary indirection operator `*`, indicating that dereferencing a "pointer to `const T` " gives you a "`const T`" (again, my emphasis):

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object.
>
> ***If the operand has type "pointer to type", the result has type "type".***

---

Finally, the `6.7.6.1 Pointer declarators /1` section, we see that the `*` belongs (for want of a better word) to the pointer type rather than the underlying object type<sup>(c) again</sup>. I've actually simplified this from the complex standards language, so see the standard if you want a complete picture:

> If the declaration is of the form `T * D`, then `D` is of the type "pointer to T".

---

**<sup>(a)</sup>** This is distinct from a "`const` pointer to `int`" (`int * const ptr`), where the pointer itself is not to be changed but the data behind the pointer may be.

Or `const pointer to const int` (`const int * const ptr`), where neither the pointer nor the thing it points to may be changed.

The `cdecl` program (or [website](https://cdecl.org/)) is a wonderful tool for gaining understanding of the declaration rules, if you're interested in further knowledge.

**<sup>(b)</sup>** There are ways to get past the `const` barrier but they tend to involve bypassing the protections, not changing the type of the pointer itself.

An example of that would be creating and using an *ephemeral* pointer without those protections, though it's likely to be undefined behaviour if the object is *actually* `const` rather than just being accessed through a pointer that *thinks* it's `const`:

```c
*((int*)cp_num) = 4;  // Legal, but butt-ugly and possibly UB :-)
//\__________/
//           \
//            This is the ephemeral pointer created from
//            cp_num, but *without* the const barrier.
```

**<sup>(c)</sup>** As an aside, this is why many developers suggest one declarator per declaration, to avoid things like:

```c
int * ptr1, ptr2; // ptr2 is an int, NOT a pointer.
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is acting as if it references *const* objects. It does not matter if you have done any pointer arithmetic with this pointer.
**It will always act that way**.

Comment: Re “The pointer is referencing a *const* objects”: In the code in the question, the pointer references `a`, which is not a `const` object. The type of the pointer is `const int *`, but that only means the C implementation must issue a diagnostic if an attempt is made to modify the object through the `const int` type. It does not mean the pointer is actually pointing to a `const` object.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The pointer declaration says "the object referenced by this pointer is `const`"  and attempts to modify it using this pointer is not legal. Assignment of the non `const` object does not change anything. You can't modify it using this pointer.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to say "The pointer is acting as if it references `const` objects", since the object itself is not `const`. Made the change, hope that's okay. If not, just revert, and suffer the slings and arrows of the language lawyers :-)